# Заниматься торговлей — управление

Tags: падежи

Как правильно: *заниматься торговлей офисной мебели или офисной мебелью / офисной техники или офисной техникой?*

Comment: Артём, большое спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Извините, а если "компания занимается торговлей оргтехники" или всё же "оргтехникой"? На слуху именно "оргтехники".

Comment: Вы действительно где-то слышали такое? Трудно представить.

Comment: Да, слышала и читала. Например здесь https://www.bysolo.by/work_as2166433.html

Comment: Удивительно, но спасибо за подтверждение. Тогда плюсую вопрос и ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тогруют **чем?** Мебелью, техникой. С "заниматься" падеж тот же: *заниматься торговлей офисной мебель**ю**/техник**ой**.*

Comment: Вот такая проверка, как вы привели, всегда работает? Например: Продают **что**? Но ведь: *Заниматься продажей офисной мебели*. Тут вопрос «Чего?», а не «Что?». Или я что-то неправильно понимаю?

Comment: Нет, не всегда это работает, но в данном случае я просто не оговорил, что с "заниматься" тот же падеж.

Comment: с заниматься тоже творительный? а если фирма занимается торговлей оргтехникИ или оргтехникОЙ?